# htmlagilitypack remove row attributes

Tags: html-agility-pack

How do we remove the inline height attribute from html?

```
<tr style="height:2px;">
</tr>
<tr style="height:2px;">
</tr>
```

I want only height attributes to be removed from all tr tags.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. If your trs have no other styles other than height, you can simply remove strip them from their style attribute (the line I commented out)
2. Otherwise, you can write something like the snippet below to filter which style keys you want to remove

   ```
   string html = @"<tr style='height:2px;'>
                   </tr>
                   <tr style='height:2px;'>
                   </tr>";

       HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
       doc.LoadHtml(html);

       var trs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("tr");

       foreach (var tr in trs)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(tr.OuterHtml);
           //tr.Attributes.Remove("style");

           var filteredStyles = GetStyles(tr.GetAttributeValue("style"), "height");
           tr.SetAttributeValue("style", string.Join(":", filteredStyles));

           Console.WriteLine(tr.OuterHtml);
       }
   ```

Helper function:

```
 private static List<string> GetStyles(string style, params string[] keysToRemove)
        {
            List<string> styles = new List<string>();
            var stylesKeyPairs = style.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (keysToRemove != null)
            {
                foreach (var styleKeyPair in stylesKeyPairs)
                {
                    var styleKeys = styleKeyPair.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    if (!keysToRemove.Contains(styleKeys.FirstOrDefault()))
                        styles.Add(styleKeyPair);
                }
            }
            else
                styles.AddRange(stylesKeyPairs);

            return styles;
        }
```

Output (for both solutions, in this case):

[image]